# Django reverse using Querydict kwargs

Tags: django, url, reverse

I've found myself in a situation, that makes me ask for help.

I've got an url with possibility of getting multiple kwargs (all named `id`).

```
url(r'^multi(id=(?P<id>\d+))*', GetView.as_view(), name='get'),
```

In GetView, after few redirects I have:

```
q = QueryDict("id=%s" %"&id=".join(list))
self.refresh_url = reverse("get", kwargs=q)
```

Where the refresh_url comes to a  refresh tag.

The problem is here:

```
Reverse for 'get' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'id': [u'123', u'456']}' not found.
```

If anyone has been in a situation like this before, than please, share your solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the id out of the url, you should use the querystring [1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist).

```
#Url
url(r'^multi/$', GetView.as_view(), name='get'),

#Reverse url
self.refresh_url = "%s?id=%s&id=%s" % (reverse("get"), id1, id2)

#Views
ids = request.GET.getlist('id')
```